# Return variable from models.py to views.py other files

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I made a form you have to fill out when uploading a file. Im using the email from the form to create a folder named after the email and i upload the file inside.

In my models.py

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.email, filename)


class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Im using `user_directory_path` to create the user_folder.
I now want to do some processing on that data but i need that exact path. 
I have a separate file that does all the processing user_processing.py or a function inside views.py for example.

In that file im importing models.py with

```
from mysite.core.models import user_directory_path
```

I imported print_filename successfully into user_processing.py

```
user_name_directory = user_directory_path(instance, filename)
```

im getting

```
name 'instance' is not defined
```

when im using that function inside models.py it has no problem getting instance, filename.

Comment: You need to import the model name User and than get the field pdf and save it in a variable and than access through that variable

Comment: I imported the class User and im assigning it to a variable and then i print the variable and im getting mysite.core.models.User', how do i select the email from it?

Comment: I tried user_name_directory = User.email and im getting django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7fe1b9647390>

Comment: solved it with User.objects.values('email')

Comment: Thats good to hear.